# The WebClient method in PowerShell. HTTP upload or FTP?

Tags: powershell, http, ftp, upload

I want to upload a file with PowerShell I've searched for uploading with the `Invoke-WebRequest` method, but I did not succeed.
Do you think the webclient method is HTTP or FTP?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

> ### Remarks
>
> The WebClient class provides common methods for sending data to or receiving data from any local, intranet, or Internet resource identified by a URI.
>
> The WebClient class uses the WebRequest class to provide access to resources. WebClient instances can access data with any WebRequest descendant registered with the WebRequest.RegisterPrefix method.
>
> **Note**
>   By default, the .NET Framework supports URIs that begin with ***`http:`, `https:`, `ftp:`***, and `file:` scheme identifiers.

Emphasis mine.